# How to paginate for hasMany relationship in laravel (App\News::user must return a relationship instance)

Tags: php, laravel

I am not able to paginate in laravel in this situation

```
return $this->hasMany('App\News','category_id')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
```

but says error. in controller I have also tried

```
$byCategories=Category::findOrFail($id)->paginate(20);`
```

it also says error.

help me.

My Model is

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function news()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\News','category_id')->orderBy('id','desc');
    }

    public function newsMany()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\News')->paginate(20);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

another model one is

```
class News extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

my controller code is

```
public  function byCategory($id)
{
     $byCategories=Category::findOrFail($id);
     return view('back-end/news/byCategory', compact('byCategories'));
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: First thing is that you should not be ordering or paginating within your relationships. You should reference the relationship and then order afterwards. For example, $category->news->orderBy('id','desc') could be a Scope but should not be explicitly defined in the relation itself. Also, are you trying to return all news ordered by category? I can't quite tell what your controller code is going for based on this code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pagination is not done in the Model
it is to be done in the controller, For example remove (->paginate(20);) from here

```
public function newsMany()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\News')->paginate(20);
}
```

keep it only as

```
public function newsMany()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\News');
}
```

and call the pagination in controller when returning the view

```
 $news=Category::findOrFail($id)->newsMany()->paginate(20);
 return view('view name', compact('news'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay but it doesn't work for me :( any other suggestion please?

Comment: Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'noya_shimanto.category_news' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `news` inner join `category_news` on `news`.`id` = `category_news`.`news_id` where `category_news`.`category_id` = 2)

Comment: If you remove the pagination does it works? I think it is not a pagination problem

Comment: Yes. it works with pagination.
My tables are
1. categories
2. news
3. publications
4. users